# Problema con método recursivo de cadenas

Tags: java, recursión

Tengo que realizar esto.
5.Cambiar la cadena para que todas las vocales estén primero que todas las consonantes y al
final coloque los *.
Por ejemplo, que reciba un cadena123 y salga un aeacdn***

No es el primer problema de recursividad que he tenido que realizar, sin embargo no encuentro la manera de realizar esto. Este es el método que he estado desarrolando sin embargo no hace lo que quiero que haga.
Agradecería su ayuda Gracias

```
private static String cambiarCadena(String cadena, int indice, int posicionActual) {

    if (indice == (cadena.length()) - 1)

    {
        cadena = comprobarCaracteres(cadena, (cadena.length()) - 1);
    } else if (cadena.charAt(indice) == 'a' || cadena.charAt(indice) == 'e' || cadena.charAt(indice) == 'i' || cadena.charAt(indice) == 'o' || cadena.charAt(indice) == 'u')
    {

        return cambiarCadena(cadena.replace(cadena.charAt(posicionActual), cadena.charAt(indice)), indice + 1, posicionActual + 1);
    } else
    {
        return cambiarCadena(cadena, indice + 1, posicionActual);
    }
    return cadena;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué hace el método comprobarCaracteres ?

Comment: Aclararme estas dudas primero van las vocales, después las consonantes y después que es lo que va que no me quedo claro en tu explicación y la otra duda es que caracteres pueden ir en la cadena, ya se que pueden ir letras y números, que otro más